# SQL Hybrid Connection Error - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, biztalk

I have a website setup in Azure Web Apps with a Biz Talk Hybrid connection to My In House SQL Database.

**Connection String includes:**

```
<add name="TjiContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:192.168.10.203,1433;Initial Catalog=TJInform_Dev;User ID=*******; Password=******;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My Hybrid connection has a host name and port defined with the same IP and port

My Database is located on the default instance and has TCP/IP enabled on port 1433

**I get the following error**

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to address the database using the External IP address we setup not our private one, which according to the Azure documentation we didn't need, strange.